# Jekyll how can I use site.data.+variable?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I would like to know if there's a way to use a variable after a data call in Jekyll?

**Like this:**

```
{% assign variable = items %}

{% assign images = site.data.folder.variable %}
```

Comment: To be more precise, I'd like to use **site.data.folder.{{variable}**} in a for loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable as an object key using this notation:

```
{% assign images = site.data.folder[variable] %}
```

Comment: I'd like to use `site.data.folder.{{ page.title }}` for example, to get the data values I need. Is it possible?

Comment: wouldn't ```site.data.folder[page.title]``` work in your use case?